# Checking if NSMutableArray contains String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm using the below code to check if a user's last name exists inside of my NSMutableArray (self.friendData). That said, even though the user last name exists inside of the self.friendData in the field "last name", it's still returning the else portion of the statement (stating it doesn't exist in the array). How can I fix this?

**ViewController.m**

```
 NSMutableDictionary *viewParams2 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [viewParams2 setValue:@"friends" forKey:@"view_name"];
    [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams2 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject2) {

        self.friendData = (NSMutableArray *)responseObject2;


        NSString *myFriend = [self.neighbourDetail objectForKey:@"last name"];

        if ([self.friendData containsObject:myFriend]) {

            NSLog(@"It contains %@!", myFriend);
            self.addFriend.hidden = YES;

        } else {
            NSLog(@"It does not contain %@", myFriend);
            self.addFriend.hidden = NO;
        }


        [operation responseString];



    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
```

**self.friendData contents:**

```
 "field_friendbio" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = "There is currently no bio available for this user.";
                    value = "There is currently no bio available for this user.";
                }
            );
        };
        "field_lastname" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = Niyo;
                    value = Niyo;
                }
            );
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `friendData` is an array of strings, I think what you really meant is this:

```
if ([self.friendData containsObject:self.neighbourDetail])
```

EDIT:

```
NSMutableArray *searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self.friendData enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    NSDictionary *friend = obj;

    if ([friend[@"field_lastname"][@"und"][@"value "] isEqualToString:myFriend])
        [searchResults addObject:friend];
}];

NSLog(@"Search Results:%@", searchResults);
```

Comment: See above edit (contents of self.friendData). I want to search friendData specifically for the last name pulled from neighbourData. That said, replacing myFriend with self.neighbourDetail still doesn't work :/

Comment: see my update, it needs to be the same data structure for `containsObject` I added the alternative solution,

Comment: I'm confused - search results is still empty when I use this code? Even if friend[@"last name"] is Equal to myFriend.

Comment: is `friendData` an array of dictionaries or models, in your edit I see `"field_lastname"` so the key need to match

Comment: Yes, friendData is an array of dictionaries. In that case, what should the above look like?

Comment: @Brittany according to what you posted the above should look like `friend[@"field_lastname"][@"und"][@"value "]`

Comment: I've changed that line to: if ([friend[@"field_lastname"][@"und"][@"value"] isEqualToString:myFriend]) , and the app crashes with the following error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17461b3f0'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132658/discussion-between-meda-and-brittany).